# Ubuntu 20.04 internet connection drops after few minutes

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager, internet

I have installed Ubuntu (dual boot along windows 10) and I have the problem that after a few minutes the internet connection drops (I am still connected with my Wifi - Network but I am not able to ping or reach a page). I do not know what the problem is. After I restart NetworkManager with systemctl restart NetworkManager it works but after a few minutes it breaks again. If I am trying to download something (e.g. sudo snap install opera) the connections also drops (but I am still connected with the network).

I am using a Dell Insprion 3593

Has anybody an idea what causes the problem?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you set the wifi router to use a single channel rather than auto and set the bandwidth so it isn't on auto?

Comment: @Jeremy31 no and all other devices work without problems. When I try to download something and it drops the ping says "ping: sendmsg: No buffer space available" Maybe ubuntu is limited for network package size? The problem only exist in ubuntu, when I am booting into windows I do not have this problem

Comment: I would take the router off the auto setting for channel and bandwidth and see if the problem is gone

Comment: @Jeremy31 problem still exist. Do not know why because I only have the problems in Ubuntu but not in windows.

Comment: That was about all I could find on your ping error

Comment: I’ve had similar issues with a ODROID XU4.  Tried 18.04 and 20.04.  Drops network after 23 mins like clockwork.   I’ve disabled ipv6 (did this ever work reliably?).  Looked over logs and don’t see anything.  Feel like this is a nail in the coffin since this board is 5 years old.   Wasted a lot of time w/o result.

Answer (score 0):

Try this command in terminal `sudo sed -i 's/3/2/' /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/*` and restart network manager by using command `sudo service network-manager restart` and if this didn't worked disable ipv6 and do the second command again.

Comment: Did it worked ? Its a the first command is to disable wifi power saving.@mymarcelsql

Comment: thank you for your reply. No unfortunately it did not work. When I restart the NetworkManager and try to download opera (sudo snap install opera) I immediately get ping: sendmsg: No buffer space available

Comment: Did you tried disabling ipv6 @mymarcelsql

Comment: Mahtre yes I tried also disabling ipv6 but it had no affect.

Comment: Ok try finding more questions and answers on internet definitely you will find a solution. Good luck.@mymarcelsql